# React router doesn't go from one post location to another

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am doing an app using React Router. My current routes are as following:

```
import React from 'react';

import App from '../components/App';
import PostList from '../components/PostList';
// import Page from '../components/Page';
import Post from '../components/Post';

export default {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  indexRoute: {
    component: PostList
  },
  childRoutes: [
    // {
    //   path: '/:slug(/:child)',
    //   component: Page
    // },
    {
      path: ':year/:month/:slug(/)',
      component: Post
    }
  ]
};
```

Everything works great, except when I am on a Post page (eg. `/2016/12/test`) and want to go to another one (`2016/12/test-2`), nothing happens. When I check the props, they change just fine.

I don't even know how to debug this strange behavior.

When I go back to the index page and visit other posts from there, everything works. What can I do?

Comment: By nothing happens, I assume you only mean that nothing inside of the page changes. Does the URL change, though? Have you tried a `componentWillReceieveProps` call in your `Post` component?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into the lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate` for your component. When this is called your new props are available and you can update your state accordingly.

Component lifecycle documentation: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md